# LyX classicthesis bibliography reference style - "et al"

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, classicthesis

I am using the classicthesis LyX template (http://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/), and was wondering how to change the format of the references in the bibliography? At the moment, the bibliography uses the plainnat style.

I want to use "et al." when there are more than 3 authors in a reference.

For example, at the moment, a reference may look like:

> [7] H R Dinse, K Krüger, A C Akhavan, F Spengler, G Schöner, and C E
>   Schreiner....

I want this to look like:

> [7] H R Dinse, K Krüger, A C Akhavan, et al. ...

Please can you help me make this change?

Many thanks.

Comment: This looks like the APA style; am I correct? (And welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.)

Comment: It uses "classicthesis.sty". The citation style is Natbib, though I don't think that is relevant? Thanks for the warm welcome!

Comment: I meant APA/MLA/Chicago…

Comment: Ohh no it's using plainnat. Whenever I try change BibTeX Generated Bibliography > style to something other than plainnat, it throws errors. I tried commenting out the the following lines in classicthesis-config.tex to no avail:
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
 \usepackage{natbib}
I'd prefer to use something like IEEEtr, but don't know how to because of errors.

Comment: I vote to close the question as unclear. The question/comments talk about errors using different bibliographystyles, but nobody knows what the errors are. Also, the `classicthesis` template was updated to use `biblatex` by now.

Answer (score 0):

In the file, classicthesis-config.tex, change the following:

Instead of:

```
maxbibnames=10
```

set it to:

```
maxbibnames=1
```

Comment: This does not answer this almost four year old question. It might answer how to do it with a recent version of the template, but still, it should be `maxbibnames=3` looking at what the OP wanted.